# How to get more info about promotional video mini-board

Tags: microcontroller, identification

As a promotional stunt, a content delivery network firm I won't name here, mailed a booklet that contained a small display that automatically started a video when opening the cover.

I was unable to temper my curiosity.

[image: Picture of promotional video booklet torn open]

To the back of the display is a board with just 3 IC's, I would guess:

- one labeled E200, which might be something like this one: [Power Architecture e200 z0 Core](http://www.power.org/solution/power-architecture-e200-z0-core/)
- flash RAM
- a video/audio controller (since it sits right on the strip to the display).

The printed text on the back of the board reads:

```
SY_AK2005
A_V1.2
2013/04/25
```

Is there a way to get more information about this set-up? There's a mini-USB port, is it only for charging the battery, or could I interface with the software/firmware on it or flash alternative firmware on it?

Comment: Actually, the chip to the left of the E200 is an SDRAM chip, and the large chip on the right is a NAND flash chip that probably contains the video file. The smaller 8-bit device above that probably contains the firmware for the E200. As far as the USB is concerned, try plugging it in and seeing if it responds to enumeration. My guess is that it will show up as a mass-storage device, and you'll be able to see the file(s) on the flash.

Comment: It would be interesting to short out various combinations of the "Kn" (keypad?) pads to see whether any additional firmware functionality is exposed.

Comment: Whaddayaknow, you're completely right. QueryDosDevice gives me these extra entries:

Comment: STORAGE#Volume#_??_USBSTOR#Disk&Ven_USB_2.0&Prod_USB_Flash_Driver&Rev_1.00#2008041123124382&0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}#{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
UMDFCtrlDev-9bdfb773-9d1f-11e3-b007-005056c00008
USB#VID_1F3A&PID_1000#2008041123124382#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}
USBSTOR#Disk&Ven_USB_2.0&Prod_USB_Flash_Driver&Rev_1.00#2008041123124382&0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}

Comment: (Hmm, McAfee found "W32/Virut.n.gen" in RUNDLL32.EXE...)